# npm ERR! Error: ENOENT "...\<non existing folder>\package.json"

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, npm

Following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

I have run `dotnet new angular -o HelloWorld`, then opened the .csproj in Visual Studio.

Next, I ran the build process and started debugging and now facing with the AggregateException error:

`AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'E:\DELETEME\HelloWorld\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json'`

Of note: `package.json` file is actually located at `E:\DELETEME\HelloWorld\ClientApp\package.json`, **NOT** `E:\DELETEME\HelloWorld\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json`

Some details about the versions:

10 error node -v v0.10.31

11 error npm -v 1.4.9

The full log in npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--port',
1 verbose cli   '52426' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.9
3 info using node@v0.10.31
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\\node\node
5 error Error: ENOENT, open 'E:\DELETEME\Testing\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json'
6 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
6 error including the npm and node versions, at:
6 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
7 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
8 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start" "--" "--port" "52426"
9 error cwd E:\DELETEME\Testing\ClientApp
10 error node -v v0.10.31
11 error npm -v 1.4.9
12 error path E:\DELETEME\Testing\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json
13 error code ENOENT
14 error errno 34
15 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

---

I did not face the above error yesterday when I started a new Angular project using the above template.

Answer (score 0):

It's been identified company's group policy was stopping Angular CLI from being able to run.